# On Haskell, how do you make an AI control a function using IO (or, how do you properly redesign it)?

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, io, functional-programming

Suppose you must define a procedure that depends on a specific decision. For example:

```
sendMonsterToGraveyard :: Game -> IO Game
sendMonsterToGraveyard game = do
    let monsters = monstersInPlay game
    monster <- choose monsters
    sendToGraveyard game monster
```

This function is an "effect" of an hypothetical game that lets the player chose one monster to kill. The problem with that design is that we are coupling the effect to the IO monad. What if, later on, we decide that we want an AI to use that effect (and, thus, chose a monster to kill)? That would be impossible other than making the AI aware of the terminal, but that doesn't sound robust. What is, thus, a proper way to redesign this pattern so that a game effect can be encoded without coupling it to the IO monad specifically?

*Note: I'm asking this upon request as a follow-up of my previous question. One of the answers actually provides a good solution for this issue, but, since it wasn't specifically addressed on the question, we decided it would be better to create a new one.*

Comment: I presume that `choose` is the only thing that uses `IO`?

Comment: Yes, it presumably asks the user which monster it wants to kill, `choose :: (Show a, Read a) => [a] -> IO a`, something like that. Of course, later on there could be other IO using primitives I'm not thinking right now.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so crazy to leave the `IO` in there; it's the easiest way to get random numbers too.

What you need to do is to pass `choose` (and whatever else is needed) as parameters into the function, so that you are accepting a parameter `choose :: Game -> [Monster] -> IO Monster` which you don't specify in advance. You might even specify these as their own `newtype`:

```
newtype MonsterChooser = MonsterChooser (Game -> [Monster] -> IO Monster)

userMonsterChooser = MonsterChooser $ \_ monsters -> loopUntilJust $ do
    let indices = zip ['a'..'z'] monsters
    putStrLn "Choose a monster to target:"
    putStrLn $ unlines $ map (\(i, monster) -> i : '.' : ' ' : show monster) indices
    index <- getLine
    return $ lookup (trim (lowercase index)) indices

loopUntilJust :: (Monad m) => m (Maybe x) -> m x
loopUntilJust mmx = do
    mx <- mmx
    case mx of Nothing -> loopUntilJust mmx
               Just x  -> return x
```

So that's a bit of a more sophisticated example, allowing you to specify a MonsterChooser. The AI gets to look at the whole `Game` before choosing a monster; the user is just asked what they want to do. Then `sendMonsterToGraveyard :: MonsterChooser -> Game -> IO Monster` is sufficiently generic that you do not need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to use a DSL.

Basically, you can just define your actions and write different interpreters for those actions, you should have something like that as result:

```
chooseMonster :: Game Monster 
chooseMonster = do
  monsters <- monstersInPlay
  monster <- chooseMonster
  sendToGraveyard monster

interpretPlayer = interpret game go
  where go action = case action of
    chooseMonster -> getMonsterFromUser
    ...

interpretAI = interpret game go
  where go action = case action of
    chooseMonster -> calculateBestMonster
    ...
```

Actually, IO is just the same thing, the only difference is that the IO action is interpreted by Haskell's runtime system. Just like that `Game` is an action, and `interpretPlayer` and `interpretAI` is different ways of executing those actions.

The [free](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) and [operational](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational) packages provide an easy way to create DSL's like that. Also, you can look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/242795/what-is-the-free-monad-interpreter-pattern .